# How does Spacebars {{#each}} work?

Tags: meteor, spacebars

I do not understand what happens with the Spacebars `{{#each}}` template tag.
For example I have a simple event code:

```
'click #player': function(){
  var playerId = this._id;
  Session.set('selectedPlayer', playerId);
  Session.set('selectedPlayerName', this.name);
}
```

And this corresponding code in the template:

```
{{#each player}}
    <a href="#" id="player" class="{{selectedClass}}"></a>
{{/each}}
```

And finally this helper:

```
'selectedClass': function(){
  return this._id
}
```

How do the event handler and the helper function knows which of the list items is being referred to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML produced by this is invalid, due to multiple elements having the same `id`-attribute. The event-handler is simple to explain. the keys inside an [`event-map`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/eventmaps) are split into `event-type` and optionally `event-target`. The `event-target` is passed to jQuery, which tolerates the invalid usage of `id`s. So jQuery adds event-listeners to all elements with the id `player`.

[Matt K explained the rest pretty well.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30964900/4386702)

Comment: Thanks! That explains everything. And thanks for noticing the bug.

Answer (score 2):

In Meteor, you've got all the Templates that you've created. Each time you render a template, you give it a data context, which is a fancy way of saying it creates a new functional scope. That data context is stored in the `templateInstance().data`.

When you use `#each`, you create a new data context for whatever is inside. you can check this by putting a `console.log(this)` in your helper above the return.

In `onCreated`, `onDestroyed`, and `onRendered`, `this` points to the `templateInstace()`. So whenever you're in a callback, use `this.data` to access the data context.

In an `events` callback you have 2 args: `event, template`. Here, `template` points to the `templateInstance()` as well.

In a helper, `this` points to `templateInstance().data` so you just need to call `this`.

Spacebars isn't magic, it's just a way to make JS look like HTML. Assuming your templates are stored in `views/templates.html`, go look at `.meteor/local/build/programs/web.browser/app/client/views/template.templates.html` and it'll all make sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have meteor installed on OS X. And it looks like I have a different folder structure. There is no /local subfolder in ~/.meteor/ , only /packages/ and /packages-metadata/. Please advice where I could look for  .meteor/local/build/programs/web.browser/app/client/views/template.templates.html ?

Answer (score 1):

[The `{{#each}}` template tag](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/spacebars/README.md#each) is special in that it changes its inner context.
In fact, each template can be used with a bag of data (for example the title and content of a post). This bag of data is registered inside the template's **own** context, and can be referred to with `this.someData` in helpers or by simply naming it in the template (`{{someData}}`).

Other template tags such as `{{#if}}` do not change the context of the template inside them. You could type inside a blog post template which receives a blog post object as data:

```
<h3>{{title}}</h3>
<p>{{content}}</p>

{{#if userIsSecretAgent}}
  <blink>{{secretData}}</blink>
{{/if}}
```

<sub>(The secret is that you had to blink at the same frequency as the text to be able to read it, that's why this tag was used for such a stupid long time)</sub>

---

`{{#each}}` allows you to change the inner context of the template to the current object of the iteration, and thus simply access the contents of the object you are iterating on.
Let's say you want to make a blog posts template which displays a list of blog posts:

```
{{#each blogPosts}}
  <!-- Here, how do you gain access to each title, each content, ..? -->
  <!-- Well, the context has changed! -->
  <!-- Now we can directly access each datum of the iterable through the context -->

  <!-- The result simply becomes: -->
  <h3>{{title}}</h3>
  <p>{{content}}</p>

  {{#if userIsSecretAgent}}
    <blink>{{secretData}}</blink>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

The context inside the `{{#each}}` block not being the same as the parent, but instead being a blog post, we can simply refer to each blog post fields by their names!

But now we're repeating code. Wouldn't it be great to reuse our previous template..?

```
{{#each blogPosts}}
  {{> blogPost}}
{{/each}}
```

The `blogPost` template needs a blog post object as its context, we are providing this context with the `{{#each}}` template tag.

Helpers work in the same way, except that you have to type `this.title` or `this.content` inside them. You also have to use [Template.instance()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_instance) to refer to the template in some places (rather than `this`).

See the [SpaceBars docs](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/spacebars/README.md) for more sorcery.